# Unable to load dynamic configurations in codeception suite configuration

Tags: php, codeception

I'm working to simplify a project's testing suite. There is a suite that uses PhpBrowser and %ABSOLUTE_URL% in the environment is set to "http://127.0.0.1:8888". The config:

```yaml
class_name: InstallTester
params:
    - env
modules:
    enabled:
        - PhpBrowser:
            url: "%ABSOLUTE_URL%"
        - \Helper\Install
```

For some reason, this project also uses an environment file travis_ci.yml:

```yaml
# `travis_ci` environment config goes here
modules:
    enabled:
        - PhpBrowser:
            url: "http://127.0.0.1:8888"
            curl:
                CURLOPT_TIMEOUT: 180
    config:
        Db:
            dsn: "mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=testdb"
            user: "root"
            password: ""
            dump: '_data/dump.sql'
            populate: true
            cleanup: false
            reconnect: true
```

The installation is run by the command:

```
codecept run install --env travis_ci
```

The PhpBrowser section in the environment file seems redundant to me. But if I remove the PhpBrowser section in travis_ci.yml, PhpBrowser fails to do the install suite. Am I understand the "params"  configuration wrong? What could be the problem?

Answer (score 1):

[Dynamic configurations with params](https://codeception.com/docs/ModulesAndHelpers#dynamic-configuration-with-parameters) is only valid in `codeception.yml`. Not the suite configuration file.

So the install suite has no need for the params section:

```yaml
class_name: InstallTester
modules:
    enabled:
        - PhpBrowser:
            url: "%ABSOLUTE_URL%"
        - \Helper\Install
```

Instead, add this section to the root level of `codeception.yml`:

```yaml
params:
    - env
```

The dynamic configurations should then work.